# How to create an ios app with friend list

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently trying to create an app with some social interaction between users (chat, localisation, etc...).

I was wondering how to be able to find the people already registered to my app, thought the iPhone contact list, to create a friend list.

**I could upload the entire list on the server to compare the phone number and/or email adresse, but I was wondering if there were something less "dirty" to do?**

FYI, my server is in nodeJS

Comment: I guess there's nothing dirty about sending a list of phone numbers and querying your db to find if they are registered

Comment: Ok... It's juste because I saw that Path had some problems for uploading the entire contacts list to their server

Comment: What or who is Path?

Comment: It's an ios app : http://mclov.in/2012/02/08/path-uploads-your-entire-address-book-to-their-servers.html. Anyway I will upload the entire list :)

Answer (score 0):

Uploading phone numbers, email addresses and other data is quite common (e.g. WhatsApp does it), but you should put some effort in

- making sure that your users understand what you are doing (you'll
  have to ask for permission anyhow)
- verifying that the phone number / email address actually belongs
  to the user
- securing the data on your server.

If you don't want to implement the logic on your own (e.g. sending SMS is quite expensive), you could use a third party library, e.g. [Fabric by Twitter](https://get.fabric.io/digits). But this comes of course at a cost (not for you as a developer, but for the user in terms that they'll hand over their data to Twitter under their terms).